# How to Download an image with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, openai-api

I want to download an image from a webpage using Node.js. The image I want to download is generated by DALLE from OpenAI and is retrieved from the API as a temporary link that expires in 1h or something. I tried scraping it with cheerio, but it doesn't work. Are there any other ways? I could also retrieve the image in base64 encoding that doesn't make much sense to me as I upload all my images on cloudinary. If anyone can help or has ideas, please let me know!

Comment: "But it doesn't work." Why doesn't it work?

Comment: cheerio cannot find a src attribute in the html. But when i check it on the page I see one

Comment: The src attribute is in the `<img>` tag.  Are you fetching the right tags?

Comment: If you have a url to an image, you don't need a scraper. Any HTTP client can do a `GET` request to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make HTTP requests using the axios library and then save the image to your local machine using the fs module

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const downloadImage = async (imageUrl, outputPath) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'stream' });
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outputPath));

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      response.data.on('end', () => {
        resolve();
      });

      response.data.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error downloading the image: ${error}`);
  }
};

// Example usage
const imageUrl = 'https://example.com/image.jpg'; // Replace with your temporary image URL
const outputPath = 'destination/folder/to/save/image.jpg'; // Replace with your desired output path

downloadImage(imageUrl, outputPath)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Image downloaded successfully!');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error downloading the image:', error);
  });
```